# Git Problem in Mac (Fatal Error)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, git, macos

I am setting up one git client on Mac (Using Source Tree). While committing the code it is showing the following error(please check the screen-shot). Any idea to solve this error ?

ERROR : [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That generally happens when your server denies your connection. There are a number of causes for getting denied:

- No/wrong SSH key (if the server uses SSH authentication)
- Wrong port set up (the server doesn't expect connections from port 22, for example)
- No/wrong username/password stored for the connection
- Server set up wrong and still denying where it should be accepting

Check all your settings to make sure everything is right.

Comment: How can I set up this SSH key ? I am using HTTP protocol and a UI Git Client named SourceTree. I am not doing it using commands. (Sorry , but I am a newbie to this thing.)

Answer (score 2):

HTTP code 501 stands for "not implemented". If the git server works over http using another client, the configuration on the client side is incorrect, so make sure you have configured the correct server address, user name and password. (If the git server doesn't work over http on any clients, the server configuration is incorrect.)

Comment: How can I set up this SSH key ? I am using HTTP protocol and a UI Git Client named SourceTree. I am not doing it using commands. (Sorry , but I am a newbie to this thing.)

Comment: If you are using HTTP, you are not using SSH and therefore don't need to set up the SSH key. You can read up about the different protocols at http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html.